# iphone screen orientation

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation

Hi I am trying to provide screen orientation in my app and I have read many docs online but when I try that It just is a total disaster (I tried emulator and iphone). On one partwhen the screen is rotated to landscape half of the views are not visible any more. Their position is on the left side and right side is empty, plus if I open a next view controller and then rotate again I can see through the second view parts of the first view it just is terrible I don't know how to fix it (Excluding blocking the possibility to lock orientation in portrait).
I know in android you can provide different xml layouts for portrait and landscape. Is there a way to fo that in iphone? If so how?

each of my views are composed of a controller and .xib
There is a "main" controller and the other controllers are called like that:

```
ayuda=[[AyudaView alloc]
               initWithNibName:@"AyudaView"
               bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:ayuda.view];
```

also I have already added these metods to the maincontroller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if(UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation)) {
    [self handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:orientation];
}

}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Screen Orientation Handling
- (void)handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
[self handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation   duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[self handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

as indicated [here](http://programmingobsession.blogspot.com/2009/05/real-world-iphone-rotation-part-1.html)
and have tried to play with the autosizing param but it only gets worse

Thank you very much

EDIT: ok I have been reading some more:

http://www.geckogeek.fr/iphone-forcer-le-mode-landscape-ou-portrait-en-cours-dexecution.html

http://www.cocoaosx.com/2011/11/10/rotatingviewcontroller-display-a-different-uiviewcontroller-depending-on-the-rotation-of-the-device/

and basically what I have found is that you have to create 2 controllers but this solution is problematic for me because of the nib files. I mean I would also have to create 2 nibs so double the amount of code (or use the library above). What if I have values in my textfields , do I just have to send them around?

Comment: You have almost no idea about how the things are supposed to work, therefore the question is fairly impossible to answer without walking you through the whole solution. And Stack Overflow is not meant to work like that. I suggest that you google some Cocoa interface orientation tutorial and slowly go through it, progressing from easier cases to more complex ones.

Comment: Have you read the Apple documentation relating to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apart from the comments suggesting you don't have any idea about what's going on in your code (which may or may not be true -- who am I to judge?), I see a few problems.

The first issue is that I don't think you understand MVC and how iOS handles the view hierarchy. You're correct in having each of your views controlled by a controller and designed by a .xib (there are cases where a view doesn't need its own controller, but for simplicity, we'll assume yours do). However, you are incorrect in the way you are presenting those views on screen. A view's controller is responsible for presenting or removing a view from the screen. The view only knows what it displays, such as labels or buttons. The controller is responsible for telling the view ***what*** to display on those labels and buttons. Instead of adding the new VC's view as a subview of your main view, push it onto a navigation controller's stack or present the view modally. If you're in your main VC, you can say

```
ayuda = [[AyudaView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:ayuda animated:YES];
```

I'm thinking that getting the view hierarchy correct might just be enough to solve your landscape/portrait swapping chaos. But while we're on that topic...why are you creating this handleInterfaceRotation method? View Controllers already have a method for this called

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

Use this method to handle rotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I was calling all my subviews the wrong way. On the other hand I have found the rotation problem and is that I was not retaining my views in the parent view, retaining them solved my problem

Comment: I would still suggest not trying to reinvent the wheel and use the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method to handle what happens when your view's orientation will change.